# Methods to deploy updates and patches to remote stand-alone machines

Tags: deployment, system-administration

I've build a solution that runs on remote, unattended machines. Sort of like interactive information kiosks. I've run into a situation where updates to the remote machines has become extremely cumbersome and I'm looking for a solution to enable the automated roll-out of updated files (binary, html, images, etc.) and to have these updates applied once pushed or downloaded.

I've investigated multiple possible solutions like DropBox, syncthing or even celery but none of these packages solve the problem in a meaningful way. I don't consider this dev-ops as the deployments are often specific to a single machine but also to all remote instances to "sync".

If anyone knows of or can suggest a stack/app/solution that can push or pull files/archives and action certain procedures upon receipt (e.g. move files to specific folders, shutdown a running binary, replace it with the new version and then restart it), I would deeply appreciate any guidance.

Comment: [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint John S Perayil! Looking into it now. I always thought Ansible was only for provisioning/initial setup.

Comment: https://www.ansible.com/continuous-delivery